# Take the array with the value more proximity

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have a set of data that I pick it up using a form and make a call to an api of a website with these data. To be a single value, did that make any checking and with that value to the call, that returned a value with the percentage that I had to subtract the value number entered on the form.

```
GET /getvalues?id={FORMNUMBER}

RETURN
{
  "id": {FORMVALUE}
  "percent": 45
}
```

Now in some cases api returns multiple values, and they have no identifier associated with each value, so would be easy, as they would only have to go and take the value of the identifier.

```
GET /getvalues?id={FORMNUMBER}

RETURN
{
  "id": {FORMVALUE},
  "values" : [
               {
                 "value": 18,
                 "percent": 10
               },{
                 "value": 45,
                 "percent": 24
               },{
                 "value": 57,
                 "percent": 32
               }
  ]
}
```

In the previous example, if the value in my form is 21 should take 18 since it has less difference between both numbers, but if the value is 40 also I take the value of 18 since it has not passed the value of 45.

I need to take the value more equal or lower than this more next to a value that pick up the form and only occurs to me do it through all the array, making a subtraction and lesser value add to an array, catching the end of lower value. Is there any way more simple do it?. I think I can only make it with a function quite long and complex, and possibly inefficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse the array (`array.reverse()`), then the function is mind-numbingly simple.

```
var values = [{"value": 18, "percent": 10}, {"value": 45, "percent": 24}, {"value": 57, "percent": 32}].reverse();
var form_value = 40;
var percent;

for ( index = 0; index < values.length; ++index ) {
  if ( form_value >= values[index].value ) {
    percent = values[index].percent;
    break;
  }
}

console.log( percent ); // 10
```

Comment: thanks you answer. The code works properly, I tried it. I've only found a problem, I put the ordered data of minor to major to explain better but the api does not have to return them so, could try to return them that way, but it really is not so. For example if I change the value of values for the following, it stops working correctly ->  [{"value": 18, "percent": 10}, {"value": 57, "percent": 32}, {"value": 45, "percent": 24}]